# DBMS_CRYPTO Performance Issues

Tags: performance, encryption, indexing, oracle10g

I'm using DBMS_CRYPTO to protect information in the case of a DB breach.  The key is not stored within the dbms, and is instead supplied by the application on each access.

A `select decrypt(name), seq order by seq` query takes (almost exactly) 15 times longer than either

```
select decrypt(name), seq
```

or

```
select name, seq order by seq
```

Which leads me to believe that the decryption function is breaking the index on the primary key `seq`.  Why would it break?

I've tried adding the keyword `DETERMINISTIC` to the function's output type, but it only cuts down the time to about 10 times longer than the faster queries.  I don't see why it should take any longer than `select decrypt(name), seq`.  **Edit**: the `DETERMINISTIC` keyword has also sped up the simple decrypt query as well, as should be expected.

Is my expectation wrong, or is it something else? I'm okay with a 300ms delay given the security constraints I've been given, but 3000ms is noticeable and I'd like to make it faster.

I'm using a DB tool called SmartSQL, which gives a "time elapsed" display (I'm assuming for time between sending the query and receiving the last bit of the result).

There is one index, the primary key, on `seq`.  I'm figuring that placing an index on the encrypted values would not help.

Execution plans:

#### select decrypt(name), seq

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                |  8810 |  1453K|    98   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CSTN_MEMB_INFO |  8810 |  1453K|    98   (3)| 00:00:02 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### select name, seq order by seq desc

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                |  8810 |  1453K|       |   428   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |                |  8810 |  1453K|  3448K|   428   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CSTN_MEMB_INFO |  8810 |  1453K|       |    98   (3)| 00:00:02 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### select decrypt(name), seq order by seq desc

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                |  8810 |  1453K|       |   428   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |                |  8810 |  1453K|  3448K|   428   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CSTN_MEMB_INFO |  8810 |  1453K|       |    98   (3)| 00:00:02 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My full queries look like this:

```
select 
    seq, gender, wdate, address, 
    my_crypto_pkg.decrypt(tel, 'my_secret_key'), 
    my_crypto_pkg.decrypt(name, 'my_secret_key') 
from cstn_memb_info
--  where my_crypto_pkg.decrypt(name, 'my_secret_key') like ?
order by
    seq desc
```

Comment: Can you post the query plans?  How are you measuring the elapsed time?  Are you measuring the time required to fetch the first row?  Or the time required to fetch the last row?  What indexes exist?  In particular, is there a composite index on (`seq`, `name`)?

Comment: Most GUI tools record the time to start returning results not the time to fetch the last result.  Most GUI tools don't try to fetch the last row unless you do something like scroll to the end of the result set.  Are you certain that SmartSQL is different from most tools (TOAD, SQL Developer, etc.) and displays the time to fetch the last row rather than the first row?

Comment: @JustinCave You're right, as I scroll down it retrieves 100 more rows at a time.  I'm not sure how it matters, though.  Also, I'm installing SQL Developer because SmartSQL isn't showing me anything other than "query succeeded" when i try an `explain plan`.  I'll add execution plans as I get them.

Comment: Can you post the full queries as well?  It appears that you're joining two tables-- is the `seq` column coming from one of these tables and the `name` from the other?  If you're comparing the runtime of different queries, it is entirely possible that the plan that gets the first row most quickly is different than the plan that gets the last row most quickly.  If you're trying to process all the rows, you probably care about the time to fetch the last row.  For some front-ends, you may prefer to optimize the time to fetch the first row.

Comment: I've modified the query and the execution plans... the other table is empty and does not affect the performance.  The goal here is to show a paginated view, so I want to retrieve rows x through x+10 after decrypting and sorting.  (I do need to decrypt first, as I will put in conditions such as `name LIKE '%something%'`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the predicate that involves decrypting the data is commented out, the time to return the first row will be very different for the three queries.  But that does not appear to be meaningful given the end result you're trying to get to.

If you eliminate the `decrypt` call, then you're just scanning the table and you don't have to call out to a separate function to decrypt the data (which is much more expensive than just reading it).  If you eliminate the `ORDER BY`, Oracle just has to decrypt the first N rows before returning data and doesn't even have to finish scanning the table.  If you decrypt the data and order the results, then you have to decrypt all the data before the sort can happen and results can start to be returned.  The time to fetch the last row will also be longest for the query that does both the `decrypt` and the `ORDER BY` but the difference will be much less dramatic.  Once you add in the predicate on the decrypted value, all the queries should get at least as slow as the slowest of the three queries which is much more in line with the query you appear to want to run in the end.

Realistically, since you intend to have a predicate on the decrypted value and since the encryption key is passed in at runtime, you're going to have to do a full scan of the table, decrypting every row, before you order the results.  That is going to be quite slow as data volumes increase.  It is also not generally compatible with what it sounds like you're describing when you talk about "a paginated view".  Since you have to decrypt every row every time you run this query, you don't want to write a query that returns the first 10 rows then issue another query to fetch rows 11-20 and so forth.  Each time you fetch a page of data, you'd need to re-decrypt every row in the table.

If you were using 11g, using the results cache functionality would potentially allow you to issue separate queries to fetch individual pages of data in a reasonably efficient fashion.  But that is not available in 10g.

Comment: That's why I'm so stumped.  They look the same but one takes 10 times as long as the other.  Even without looking at the time the tool gives me, one seems to load instantly while the other obviously takes a few seconds.

Comment: @bdares - Are you certain that you are accounting for differences in what data is cached?  Are you, for example, running each query 3 times in succession (fetching all rows each time) and using only the 3rd execution time (the first two executions serving to cache the data)?  If you run the queries in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer) with autotrace enabled, are you seeing differences in the amount of work actually being done?

Comment: I'll get back to you on what autotrace says after I get the necessary privileges, but running the slower (decrypt and order by) query multiple times in succession will still take several seconds each, while the faster ones will always take under half a second at most.

Comment: @bdares - Are you measuring with the predicate that involves decrypting the data commented out?  Or with it in place?

Comment: commented out, for now... I'm sure it will slow it down more when I actually use it, but for now I'm interested in making the current query work faster.